# Not show column name from database on Jtable

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, awt

I write the program to retrieve data from database to show on `JTable`. The program can run without the error but It doesn't show the column name. Here the code:

```
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection("" +"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Store;user=sa;password=t81iS17Zxj");
    Statement sqlstatement = dbcon.createStatement();
    ResultSet dbresultset = sqlstatement.executeQuery("select * from Store.dbo.Product");
    rsmetadata = dbresultset.getMetaData();       // Get metadata on them
    numcols = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();    // How many columns?
    //  Get column names

    for (int i = 1; i <= numcols; i++)
    {
        defaultmodel.addColumn( rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
    }
    //  Get row data

    while (dbresultset.next())
    {
        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(numcols);

        for (int i = 1; i <= numcols; i++)
        {
            row.addElement( dbresultset.getObject(i) );
        }

        defaultmodel.addRow(row );
    }
```

I try to print the value of `rsmetadata.getColumnName(i)` out and then `Eclipse` show me the column name but why in the above,it doesn't show.

Comment: How are you displaying your JTable? What kind of component are you storing it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The program can run without the error but It doesn't show the column name.

The column names are only displayed when you add the table to a JScrollPane. So somewhere in your code you need something like:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
panel.add( scrollPane );
```

For a complete working example you can use the `Table From Database Example` found in [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/).

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code :-

This code return column name with data from database

```
      int col_count=0;

      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      Connection dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection("" +"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Store;user=sa;password=t81iS17Zxj");
      Statement sqlstatement = dbcon.createStatement();
      ResultSet dbresultset = sqlstatement.executeQuery("select * from Store.dbo.Product");


     Vector column_name=new Vector();   
     column_name=new Vector();   
    ResultSetMetaData rsm= dbresultset .getMetaData();
     col_count=rsm.getColumnCount();

    for(int a=0;a<col_count;a++)
      {
         column_name.addElement(rsm.getColumnLabel(a+1)); 

      }

    Vector newRow=null,nRow;
    Vector row=new Vector();

    while(dbresultset .next())
    {
        newRow =new Vector();
       for(int j=0;j<col_count;j++)
        {
         newRow.addElement(dbresultset .getObject(j+1));
         }

         row.addElement(newRow);

        }

     DefaultTableModel model= new DefaultTableModel(row, column_name);

      ztable.setModel(model);
```

Comment: Basically your solution is to create a new DefaultTableMode with the rows and columns vector. Worth a try, though your code (formatting) leaves a bit to desire, _Welcome to StackOverflow._